# In Sencha Touch 2 how to customize loading mask and sort the list items when using ListPaging

Tags: sorting, sencha-touch-2, loading

I have 2 questions:

1.I don't like the loading mask in ListPaging, is there any way to customize it?
Here is my code:

the store

```
Ext.define('tyoa.store.request.Documents', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'tyoa.model.request.Document',
    storeId: 'documents',
    pageSize:10,
    // autoSync:true,
}
});
```

The method in Controller,it will load first page and show up the view:

```
showYuejianRequestView:function(){
    storeDocuments = Ext.getStore('documents');
    storeDocuments.removeAll();
    storeDocuments.setProxy({
        type:'ajax',
        limitParam:'limit',
        pageParam:'page',
        url:Global.API+'/request/bangongting/requestConsultList.jsp',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'requestConsult',
            totalProperty:'total',
        }
    }); 
    storeDocuments.loadPage(1);
    var requestList = Ext.create('tyoa.view.request.RequestConsultList');
    global.viewDirectionLeft(requestList);
},
```

The list view:

```
Ext.define('tyoa.view.request.RequestConsultListDetail',{
extend:'Ext.List',
alias:'widget.requestConsultListDetail',
xtype:'requestConsultListDetail',
requires: ['Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
               'Ext.field.Search',
               'Ext.data.JsonP'],   
config:{
    //emptyText: '没有已办过的文件！',
    plugins:[
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: false,
            noMoreRecordsText: 'No more',
            loadMoreText: 'Load more...'
        },
    ],
    cls: 'x-contacts',      
    itemTpl: [
       '<div class="headshot"><img src='+Global.IMG+'{createUserImgUrl} width="37" height="37"/></div>',
        '{senderName}',
        '<img width="20" height="27" style="float:right; margin:5px 0px;" src="resources/images/arrow.png" />',
        '<span class="time">{sendTime}</span>',
        '<tpl if="title!=null"><span>{title}</span></tpl>',
        '<tpl if="title==null"><span>{content}</span></tpl>',              
    ].join(''),
    store: 'documents'
}
});
```

2.How to sort the list items in listpaging(say sort items by time)? I once use this in store,

```
sorters: [
    {
        property: 'timeStr',
        direction: 'DESC'
       },
   ],
```

however,when i load the 2nd page,the two pages' items will stir together and resort again,thus you cannot tell which are 1st page's which are 2nd's,i don't want that happen.
Any help or hint will be appreciated,thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago,one of my colleagues solved the question. In `/sdk/src/dataview/DataView.js` (in `st 2.0`), at line 785, you will see

```
if (loadingText) {
    this.setMasked({
       xtype: 'loadmask',
       message: loadingText
});
```

just override it, for example:

```
if (loadingText) {
    this.setMasked({
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        indicator: false,
        message:'<img src="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>',
        messageCls:'width:48px;'
});
```

the list paging loading mask will be changed! Never thought it was in `DataView.js`.